# Stable planetary rotation states

Tags: planets, rotation

In reading an article about theories as to how the slow retrograde rotation of Venus may have come into being, the article [Why Venus Spins the Wrong Way](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=why-venus-spins-the-wrong) (Franzen, 2001) stated that

> it is bound to settle into one of four stable rotation states, two in either direction.

The 'direction', referring to the direction of rotation (retrograde or 'normal').

What are these four rotation states and what physical principles govern them?

Comment: The [original article](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v411/n6839/abs/411767a0.html) was nontrivial to find, since the summary you linked misspelled one of the author's names.

Comment: ... and that original article is extraordinarily terse and dense - it looks like it will require at least half a dozen references just to figure out what their symbols mean.

Comment: The original article is behind a paywall, but there are two follow-up papers that are freely available: [this one](http://www.imcce.fr/Equipes/ASD/preprints/prep.2002/venus1.2002.pdf) and [this one](http://www.imcce.fr/Equipes/ASD/preprints/prep.2002/venus2.2002.pdf). There is also a [website](http://www.imcce.fr/Equipes/ASD/Venus/venus0_en.html).